# Where is the link of Parse data browser in parse.com website?

Tags: parse-platform

Simply to say, i can not find the Parse Data Browser and really don't know what is it. is it a link of parse site or a software or ... ?
I've tried google for that and a couple of youtube videos about that but i think anybody knows what it is and how to find it except me.

Comment: what you're looking for is http://back4app.com.  Facebook (who owned Parse) stopped actually **hosting** Parse a couple years ago.  You can host it yourself, or your client can host it, but almost everyone just uses **back4app**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse.com is down now, you can see [this](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/a-parse-shutdown-reminder/) but you can have your own parse server because parse is open source

Install your [parse-server](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server) and set-up your [parse-dashboard](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-dashboard)

All documentation is available [here](http://parseplatform.org/)

- If you want to start quickly you can host your parse-server on [Heroku](https://heroku.com) or use [back4app](https://www.back4app.com)
- If you are looking for an alternative solution you can use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com)

Comment: Right, 99.9% of parse is just on back4app.com.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running your own parse-server, you just have to add the parse-dashboard module. It's pretty easy to set up. https://github.com/parse-community/parse-dashboard#local-installation

You can mount it right on the same app your parse-server is hosted from, or keep it separate and just run it locally.